# What is the exact definition for calculating multiple sums?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, summation, permutations

Let $S$ be a finite set, and $(Y, +)$ an Abelian group. Let $g: S \rightarrow Y$.

Summation over $S$ is defined as follows:
$$ \sum_{x\in S} g(x) := \sum_{i=1}^{\left| S\right|} g(\sigma(i)),$$
where $\sigma$ is any bijective map from $ \left\{1, 2, \dots, \left|S\right|\right\} $ to $S$. It turns out that this is well defined.

Not, let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f: S^n \rightarrow Y$. Similarly as before, the summation over all n-tuples $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in S^n$ is
$$ \sum_{\left(x_1{,}\ \dots{,}\ x_n\right)\in S^n}^{ }f\left(x_1{,}\ \dots{,}\ x_n\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\left|S\right|^n}f\left(\pi\left(i\right)\right), $$
where $\pi:\ \left\{1{,}\ 2{,}\ \dots{,}\ \left|S\right|^n\right\}\rightarrow S^n$ is any bijection.

However, it is unclear to me, how $\sum_{\left(x_1{,}\ \dots{,}\ x_n\right)\in S^n}^{ }f\left(x_1{,}\ \dots{,}\ x_n\right)$ is the same as
$$\sum_{x_1{,}\ \dots{,}\ x_n\in S}^{ }f\left(x_1{,}\ \dots{,}\ x_n\right):=\sum_{x_1\in S}^{ }\sum_{x_2\in S}^{ }\dots\sum_{x_n\in S}^{ }f\left(x_1{,}\ \dots{,}\ x_n\right) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ (1)$$
and that the RHS of $(1)$ is even well defined.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, fixed it.